# What does the number between the line number and project dock mean in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

[View photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNkn.jpg)

What does the number between the line number and project dock mean in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question. In PyCharm, you have the ability to add what is called a mnemonic bookmark, to help you remember the significance of a particular bookmark.

[image: Mnemonic Bookmark]